# The difference between creating a function in a class and in a method build

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have used idea 2 in my project but I have not seen any source using the same !!
Will there be any difference?**

```
class Untitled extends StatelessWidget {
      const Untitled({
        Key key,
      }) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final title = 'demo';

        // idea 1
        final text = _buildTextTitle(title);
        // idea 2
        final text = (() {
          if (title.isEmpty) {
            return 'Input text empty!';
          }

          return title;
        })();

        return Text(text);
      }

      String _buildTextTitle(String title) {
        if (title.isEmpty) {
          return 'Input text empty!';
        }

        return title;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly the same effect, but sometimes you will use your function in a single place and you don't want to define it, so you use your second idea.